# To get the offset values from jquery

Tags: jquery

How do i find the offset value of an image, which is enclosed with in a table. The table consist of lot of images. i want to get the offset - left, right, top, bottom for all the image while hover into the image. **I need this in jquery**

Thanks,
Praveen J

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var elem = $("your_element");
var offset = elem.offset();
var leftValue = offset.left;
var topValue =  offset.top;
```

To get right and bottom values add width and height values to left and top..

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com).  These functions are all very clearly spelled out.

```
$("#yourImg").bind("mousemove", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var imgLeft = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
    var imgTop = e.pageY - $this.offset().top;
    var imgBottom = $this.offset().top + $this.height() - e.pageY;
    var imgRight = $this.offset().left + $this.width() - e.pageX;

    // do more stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little plugin that does just this.

It gets the position of the element that you want; left, right, top or bottom; relative to it's parent or to the HTML document.

You can find it on my github: https://github.com/Ridle/jQuery-getOffsets